# Java Regex for Extracting Monetary Phrases

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find the regex to extract a specific type of monetary phrase from text, but I'm having trouble. The type of monetary phrase I want to extract

1. must start with a "$",
2. immediately followed by any sort of number,
3. then followed by a space, and finally
4. followed by either the word "million" or "billion".

So for example, the regex should match the following phrases:

```
$12 million
$6.2 billion
```

The regex should not match the following phrases:

```
$5 thousand
$ 3 million
$3.6
```

The regex I came up with was

```
"$+\\\\d+\\\\s+(billion|million)"
```

, but it didn't work when I tested it. Can someone help me out? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape `$` to match `$` literally. And backslash(`\`) should escaped when used in Java string literals.

Replace `\$+` with `\$` unless you mean to match multiple `$` like `$$$$`.

```
"\\$\\d+\\s+(billion|million)"
```

To match `$6.2 billion`, the regular expression should be modified:

```
"\\$\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\s+(billion|million)"
```

- `(billion|million)` could be written as `[mb]illion` as @Keppil suggest.

Comment: I would rewrite `(billion|million)` as `[mb]illion`. No need for the capture group.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, Thank you for comment. I updated the code according to you.

Comment: @Keppil, I updated the answer to mention that. Thank you for comment.